# WhatsApp Video Calls Auto-Turn-On Continuity Camera

Tags: macos, ios, camera, continuity, sonoma

How do I make Mac remember that for WhatsApp video calls specifically, the continuity Camera should be off, i.e. the video input feed shouldn't auto jump to my iPhone's camera but use Mac's instead?